# Spring MockMvc does seems not support "produces" in @RequestMapping when using WebApplicationInitializer

Tags: spring, spring-test-mvc

I have the following method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/report.txt", produces = "text/plain;charset=UTF-8", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public String showReport(
  ...
)
```

which I test with:

```
@Before
public void setup() throws Exception {
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();
}

@Test
public void reportPage() throws Exception {
    mockMvc.perform(get("/report.txt"))
        .andDo(print())
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
        .andExpect(content().contentType("text/plain;charset=UTF-8"))
```

`.andDo(print())` tells me 
    `Content-Type=[text/plain;charset=ISO-8859-1]`

It seems like the content type in the "produces" attribute is not used by MockMvc. When I'm running the app in jetty the content type for this page is correct.

This started after we began using WebApplicationInitializer.

I'm on Spring 4.2.2.RELEASE.

Has anyone else here seen this issue? Any ideas for a workaround?

Thanks!

-Kaj :)

Comment: I did a check in one of my applications and Spring MVC Test behaves normally. I set `produces` to `text/plain;charset=ISO-8859-2` and `andDo(print())` shows the same `contentType`. It looks like there is something broken in your configuration. `WebApplicationInitializer` has nothing to do with your problem. `WebApplicationInitializer` gets only picked up by a servlet container. Spring MVC Test does not rely on a servlet container.

Comment: i think like @ksokol . I have similar tests and everything is working ok.

Comment: Thank you for your comments! :)

Comment: I've got the same problem as you, and I found that adding @EnableWebMvc in my unit test class does solve it. Not yet sure why, though.

Answer (score 0):

```
        this.mockMvc.perform(get("/handle").accept(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN))
        .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.valueOf("text/plain;charset=ISO-8859-1")))
        .andExpect(content().contentType("text/plain;charset=ISO-8859-1"))
        .andExpect(content().contentTypeCompatibleWith("text/plain"))
        .andExpect(content().contentTypeCompatibleWith(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN));
```

From this link https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-test/src/test/java/org/springframework/test/web/servlet/samples/standalone/resultmatchers/ContentAssertionTests.java.